# Add UiParameter to UIAjaxFunction programmatically

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, parameters, programmatically-created

This is a short example of using richfaces jsFunction with parameter.

```
<r:jsFunction name="addTag" action="#{bean.method}">
   <r:param name="param" assignTo="#{bean.tagId}"/>
</r:jsFunction>
```

then you can use from javascript addTag('1') and the parameter will be stored to the bean.

I need to accomplish the same functionality creating the jsFunction and ading parameter programmatically. This is the code that I use but not works:

```
UIAjaxFunction jsFunctionAddTag = new UIAjaxFunction();
jsFunctionAddTag.setName("addTag");
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExpressionFactory ef = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
MethodExpression me = ef.createMethodExpression(fc.getELContext(), "#{bean.method}", 
                      null, new Class[]{});
jsFunctionAddTag.setActionExpression(me);
UIParameter param = new UIParameter();
param.setName("param");
param.setAssignToExpression(ef.createValueExpression(fc.getELContext(), 
                            "#{bean.tagId}", String.class));
jsFunctionAddTag.getChildren().add(param);
```

When the method is executed the value of tagId is not setted. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround in the server side the parameter can be obtained from the ExternalContext:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String paramValue = (String)map.get("paramName");
```